# I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS in creating NSString using stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, segmentation-fault, nsstring, exc-bad-access, kern-invalid-address

Stack trace:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff2021a26e objc_opt_respondsToSelector + 27
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20405674 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 9123
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff20534412 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsReturningMetadata + 145
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff204032cb _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 20
4   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff210d1eef +[NSString stringWithFormat:] + 153
```

Faulting Code:

```
NSString* GetPlistPath(){
    return [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",UserLibrary,PREFERENCE_PLIST_DIR_NAME,PREFERENCE_PLIST_NAME] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
}
```

Where `UserLibrary` is an `NSString*` and `PREFERENCE_PLIST_DIR_NAME` and `PREFERENCE_PLIST_NAM`E are `NSString* const`.

Comment: You sure about PREFERENCE_PLIST_DIR_NAME and PREFERENCE_PLIST_NAME? Maybe they are just `char *`. Show how you define them.

Comment: Can you reproduce it? Then check the value of each variable. Show how they are defined?

Comment: static NSString* const PREFERENCE_PLIST_NAME=@"SomeString";

Also, I am not able to reproduce this issue. A few cases have been reported from some customers.

Comment: OK, show how you set `UserLibrary` as well